# Covariance of absolute values of random vaiables

Tags: absolute-value, covariance

How would I go about calculating $\operatorname{cov}(|X|,|Y|)$, if I know $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$ ?

Comment: If we know the joint density, we can calculate the covariance of $|X|$ and $|Y$|$ with the usual formula.

Comment: Thanks, how so? When integrating to find expectations, would we just use | _x_ | and | _y_ | instead of _x_ and _y_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ of $X$ and $Y$, then $\text{Cov}(|X|,|Y|)$ is dealt with in the usual way. For 
$$E(|X|)=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} |x| f_{X,Y}\,dx\,dy,$$
with a similar expression for $E(|Y|)$. And
$$E(|XY|)=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} |xy| f_{X,Y}\,dx\,dy.$$
We can now use $\text{Cov}(U,V)=E(UV)-E(U)E(V)$ to finish.